# How to solve The name "connectionclass" does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#

So, I want to make a drop down list. I have the connectionclass.cs, which connects the database to an array list. But when I build the dropdown list, doesn't find the connectionclass

Sorry, i am a  bit tired. So, this is the classconnection.cs.

[There is the ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn4zT.png)

```
   namespace YourCoffeeShop.App_Code
    {
        public static class ConnectionClass
        {
            private static SqlConnection conn;
            private static SqlCommand command;
            static ConnectionClass()
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cafeaconnection"].ToString();
                    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
            }
            public static ArrayList GetCafeaByType(string cafeaType)
            {
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tipuridecafea WHERE tip LIKE '{0}'", cafeaType);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        string nume = reader.GetString(1);
                        string tip = reader.GetString(2);
                        double pret = reader.GetDouble(3);
                        string roast = reader.GetString(4);
                        string tara = reader.GetString(5);
                        string imagine = reader.GetString(6);
                        string review = reader.GetString(7);

                        cafeacs tipuridecafea = new cafeacs(id, nume, tip, pret, roast, tara, imagine, review);
                        list.Add(tipuridecafea);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                return list;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure `GetShirtByType` is static?

Comment: 1) What error does it give? 2) Is "GetShirtByType" a static method on the ConnectionClass?

Comment: Can you post a broader example? Where is connectionclass declared?

Comment: Please show your `connectionclass.cs` file.

Comment: The GetShirtByType is static, and the error is exactly that: The 'connectionclass' does not exist in the current context

Comment: If I take the code you have posted and compile it, will it compile? No. Then we cannot help. You need to give us enough code so we can make sense of it.

Comment: The name is `ConnectionClass`, but you try to call the method of `connectionclass`. A simply typo.

Comment: I realised that, and i changed the code, but the result is the same.

Comment: It looks like you may have deleted some relevant code when posting an update.  Many of the previous comments are referencing a GetShirtByType method that is not present anymore.

Comment: This is the actual code. That was just an example, but then i realised that you need much more. Sorry

Comment: Could it be that you are missing a `using` statement?  Your `ConnectionClass` is defined in namespace `YourCoffeeShop.App_Code` yet according to your image, you are attempting to use it inside your `Cafea` class which is inside `YourCoffeeShop.Pages` namespace.

Comment: I tried using YourCoffeeShop.App_Code too, but no result

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your entire class, but the answer is that C# is **case-sensitive**, so:

```
ArrayList shirtList = connectionclass.GetShirtByType(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

is not equivalent to:

```
ArrayList shirtList = ConnectionClass.GetShirtByType(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Provided that the `.GetShirtByType(...)` method exists in the class and is `static`, the second example above would correct your error.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the problem was. I went into ConnectionClass.cs properties and changed the build action to compile and then added the using YourCoffeeShop.App_Code. It works now, thanks everyone!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50418482/edit) to include the code, don't post it as an answer.